# Pasar una imagen con un texto a otra pagina a través de un botón

Tags: html, css, eclipse, botón

ya he formulado esta preguntado pero era bastante general, y a la hora de la ayuda no la entendieron. Tengo una pagina con una foto, su nombre(texto), y otras cosas irrelevantes como descripción, precio, características... además de unos botones. Pues bien el botón a "añadir al carro" quiero que me coja esa foto con su texto(nombre de la foto) y me la lleve a otra página(como la página del carrito de la compra por ejemplo). Solo necesito que se muevan esas dos cosas. Estoy usando el IDE de Eclipse con java para una aplicación web. Me gustaría hacer esto sin tener que usar ninguna BBDD, repositorio ni nada; aunque en la aplicación he usado mysql y apache tomcat. Aquí les dejo el código.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
 crossorigin="anonymous">
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> 
 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<title>Vapers de LGS</title>
</head>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('.carousel').carousel({
       duration:5
     });
   
    $('.next').click(function(){
      $('.carousel').carousel('next');            
    });
    
    $('.prev').click(function(){
     $('.carousel').carousel('prev');
   });
 });
 
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" lang="JavaScript">

function paraAtras() {
    document.location.href = "vapers.html"
}

function paraCarro() {
    document.location.href = "carro.html"
}

function paraCompra() {
    document.location.href = "compra.html"
}

</script>


<!-- Algunos de los estilos de la página de vapers entre ellos el fondo, los textos, colores, fotos... -->

<style>

body {
 background-image:
  url("https://d1di2lzuh97fh2.cloudfront.net/files/2f/2fq/200/2fqq8a.png?ph=6fd8d12f56");
 text-align: center;
}

h1 {
 color: green;
 font-size: 55px;
 font-style: italic;
 font-weight: bold;
}

p {
 color: green;
 font-family: fantasy;
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

p1 {
 color: white;
 font-size: 25px;
}

p2 {
 color: white;
 font-family: fantasy;
 font-size: 20px;
}

p3 {
 color: white;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: left;
}

p4 {
 color: white;
 font-family: fantasy;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.vaper1 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.vaper1 p1 {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: x-large;
  width: 90%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.vaper1 p2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: large;
  text-align: left;
  width: 90%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.carousel .carousel-item img {
    width: 150%;
    max-height: 300px;
    align: center;
}

.carousel-item {
 transition: 1.0s ease all;
}

</style>

<!-- Aquí va la estructura de la visualización de las fotos de los vapers con sus respectivos nombres y precios -->

<body>

 <h1>Le Grow Shop</h1>
 <p>Los mejores Vapers de Leganés</p>
 
    <div class="carousel" data-indicators="true" adaptiveHeight="true">
  <a class="carousel-item"><img src="https://www.vaperss.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/smok-vape-pen-22-kit-1650-mah-batera-e-cigarrillo-negro-2ml-tpd-cumple-600x600.jpg"></a> 
  
  <a class="carousel-item"><img src="https://www.vaperss.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/smok-vape-pen-box-contents-768x673.jpg"></a> 

  <a class="carousel-item"><img src="https://www.vaperss.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/86.jpg"></a> 

  <a class="carousel-item"><img src="https://www.vaperss.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/smok_vape_pen_22_starter_kit_6_.jpg"></a> 

   </div>
 
 <p1><strong>Vaper Fino Negro/Gris 24,99€</strong></p1>
 
 <br></br>
 
 <div class="btn green  waves-effect prev" align="center">Anterior</div>
 <div class="btn green  waves-effect next" align="center">Siguiente</div>
 
 <br></br>
 
 <div type="button" class="btn purple waves-effect back" align="center" onclick="paraAtras()">Atrás</div>
 
 <br></br>
 <br></br>

    <div class="vaper1">
      <p1><strong><li type="disc">Descripción:</li></strong></p1>
      <p2><strong>Vaper Smok 22 Pen, vaper simple pero con buena capacidad. Si eres un novato en el mundo de los vapers, que lo eres, no digas
       que no; este es una de las mejoras opciones para empezar. El vaper incluye dos resistencias, un cable y cargador, una boquilla, una 
       goma de proteccion y un vaper SMOK con batería interna incluida.</strong></p2>
      <p1><strong><li type="disc">Características:</li></strong></p1>
      <p2><strong><li type="circle">Fabricado en acero inoxidable</li></strong></p2>
      <p2><strong><li type="circle">Medidas: 22 x 110mm</li></strong></p2>
      <p2><strong><li type="circle">Bateria interna de 1650 mAh</li></strong></p2>
      <p2><strong><li type="circle">Capacidad de depósito de 2.0 ml</li></strong></p2>
      <p2><strong><li type="circle">Funcionamineto sencillo</li></strong></p2>
      <p2><strong><li type="circle">Conexión: Conector 510</li></strong></p2>
      <p2><strong><li type="circle">Estructura desmontable</li></strong></p2>
      <p2><strong><li type="circle">Puerto micro usb</li></strong></p2>
    </div>
    
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    
    <div type="button" class="btn purple waves-effect back" align="center" onclick="paraAtras()">Atrás</div>
    <div type="button" class="btn orange waves-effect front" align="center" onclick="paraCarro()">Añadir al Carro</div>
    <div type="button" class="btn red waves-effect front" align="center" onclick="paraCompra()">Comprar</div>
    
    <br></br>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar a usar en php con la función `$_GET`
Te dejo aquí un ejemplo :).
https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.get.php

Lo único que tendrías que hacer seria cambiar tu función tal que asi.

```
 function paraCarro() {
    document.location.href = "carro.html?foto=https://taltal.com&texto=foto"
}
```

Y seleccionar lo de "foto" y "taltal.com" con variables en php o javascript como prefieras. Después en la página de destino pones

```
<?php
$foto = $_GET['foto']; 
$texto= $_GET['texto'];
?>
```

y puedes mostrarlas con `<?php echo $foto; ?> <?php echo $texto; ?>`
Espero haberte ayudado ;),

Comment: No lo entiendo muy bien amigo, el código se refiere a que al usarlo coge el parámetro en este caso un texto para ponerlo en una cadena de caracteres no?

Comment: Si, el código transpasa los datos mediante la url utilizando la función $_GET.

Comment: Mas o menos lo he entendido ya he configurado la ruta de la función con la url de la foto y el nombre de la misma, pero en la pagina donde deseo que vayan esos datos he puesto el codigo $_GET y al intentar ver si funcionan pulsando el boton me lleva a la pagina destino pero esta en blanco. Puede que haya sido error mio, he usado javascript para poner el codigo suministrado pero no me funciona

Comment: Para poner el código suministrado tienes que usar php <?php ?>

Comment: Estando los datos tal como te voy a mostrar ahora en el ejemplo

Comment: Y para mostrarlas tienes que poner el <?php echo $foto; ?> y <?php echo $texto; ?>

Comment: No si lo he entendido he usado tanto javascipt para el get como php para la visualizacion

Comment: Para el get tienes que usar php, tienes arriba el código que tienes que poner encima de <html> y de todo.

Comment: Sin escribir <script> claro

Comment: para la visualización puedes poner <?php echo $foto; ?> <?php echo $texto; ?> estás lineas sea dentro de un código javascript o sea en el html donde deberia ir cada texto.

Comment: Amigo ya tenia todo ordenado lo de php del get estaba ya arriba de todo y la visualizacion lo meti dentro de un script <script type="text/javascript" lang="JavaScript">

<?php echo $foto; ?> 
<?php echo $texto; ?>

</script>

Comment: Quita lo de script. Con lo de meterlo en un script me refiero si quieres dar valores a alguna variable. Pero solo para visualizarlo haz asi <?php echo $foto; ?> <?php echo $texto; ?>

Comment: Lo he metido dentro del body, debajo de un par de lineas de texto que he puesto pero nada, antes estaba debajo del html y antes del body. Gracias por la ayuda igualmente.

Comment: Me puedes decir la url¿?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95375/discussion-between-markostech-and-alex).